# Assignment from incompatible pointer type in Eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, pointers, ubuntu

I have seen many questions on this topic, but couldn't take much sense from them and couldn't compare it to my code. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it appears as a warning on Eclipse, and I think it might be what's making my function behave differently than it should.

The comments and variables are in portuguese, so if you need me to translate any part of it, or to tell you what each function should do, just tell me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "grafo.h"

typedef struct _relemento
{
    /** string armazenada */
    char *nome;
    int x, y, id;
    struct _elemento *proximo;
} robot_lista;

typedef struct
{
    robot_lista *raiz;
    int tamanho;
} listarobots;

typedef struct _elemento
{
    /** string armazenada */
    int x;
    int y;
    int v;
    struct _elemento *proximo;
} elemento_lista;

typedef struct
{
    elemento_lista *raiz;
    int tamanho;
} lista;


listarobots* listarobots_nova()
{
    /* cria lista */
    listarobots *lst = (listarobots*) malloc(sizeof(listarobots));
    if(lst == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* lista esta' vazia */
    lst->raiz = NULL;
    lst->tamanho = 0;

    return lst;
}

robot_lista* novorobot_str(const char* valor, int x, int y, int id)
{
    /* aloca memoria para a estrutura lista */
    robot_lista *item = (robot_lista *) malloc(sizeof(robot_lista));
    if(item == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* aloca memoria para string */
    item->nome = (char *) malloc((strlen(valor)+1)*sizeof(char));
    if(item->nome == NULL)
    {
        free(item);
        return NULL;
    }

    /* copia valor */
    strcpy(item->nome, valor);
    item->x=x;
    item->y=y;
    item->id=id;
    /* item ainda nao tem proximo */
    item->proximo = NULL;

    return item;
}

int listarobots_insere(listarobots *lst, const char* valor, int x, int y,int id)
{

    robot_lista *curr = NULL, *temp;

    if (lst == NULL)
        return -1;

    temp = lst->raiz;

    /* cria novo item */
    curr = novorobot_str(valor, x, y, id);

    if (curr == NULL)
        return -1;

    lst->tamanho++;


    curr->proximo = temp;
    lst->raiz = curr;
    return 1;

}

int listarobot_pesquisa(listarobots *lst, const char* str, int* x, int* y, int *id)
{
    int i=0;
    robot_lista *aux;

    if(lst == NULL)
        return -1;

    /* pesquisa sequencial */
    for (aux = lst->raiz; aux != NULL; aux = aux->proximo, i++)
    {
        if (strcmp((aux->nome), str) == 0)
        {
            *x= aux->x;
            *y= aux->y;
            *id= aux->id;
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int listarobot_atribui(listarobots *lst, int pos, int x, int y)
{
    int i=0;
    robot_lista *aux;

    if (lst == NULL || pos < 0)
        return -1;

    aux = lst->raiz;

    /* procura item na posicao pos */
    for (i = 0; i < pos && aux != NULL; i++)
        aux = aux->proximo;

    /* se aux e' NULL entao nao existe posicao pos */
    if (aux == NULL)
        return -1;
    aux->x=x;
    aux->y=y;
    return pos;
}




lista* lista_nova()
{
    /* cria lista */
    lista *lst = (lista*) malloc(sizeof(lista));
    if(lst == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* lista esta' vazia */
    lst->raiz = NULL;
    lst->tamanho = 0;

    return lst;
}
elemento_lista* novo_str(int x, int y, int v)
{
    /* aloca memoria para a estrutura lista */
    elemento_lista *item = (elemento_lista *) malloc(sizeof(elemento_lista));
    if(item == NULL)
        return NULL;

    item->v=v;
    item->x=x;
    item->y=y;

    /* item ainda nao tem proximo */
    item->proximo = NULL;

    return item;
}

int lista_insere(lista *lst, int x, int y, int v)
{
    elemento_lista *curr = NULL, *temp;

    if (lst == NULL)
        return -1;

    temp = lst->raiz;

    /* cria novo item */
    curr = novo_str(x,y,v);

    if (curr == NULL)
        return -1;

    lst->tamanho++;

    curr->proximo = temp;
    lst->raiz = curr;
    return v;

}

int lista_pesquisa(lista *lst, int x, int y)
{
    int i=0;
    elemento_lista *aux;

    if(lst == NULL)
        return -1;

    /* pesquisa sequencial */
    for (aux = lst->raiz; aux != NULL; aux = aux->proximo, i++)
    {
        if ((aux->x==x) && (aux->y==y))
        {
            return aux->v;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int lista_xy (lista *lst, int v, int *x , int* y)
{
    int i=0;
    elemento_lista *aux;

    if(lst == NULL)
        return -1;

    /* pesquisa sequencial */
    for (aux = lst->raiz; aux != NULL; aux = aux->proximo, i++)
    {
        if ((aux->v==v))
        {
            *x=aux->x;
            *y=aux->y;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}













void leitura(int *tamx,int *tamy,int *xminfinal, int* yminfinal, int *wx, int *wy, int *fimx, int *fimy, FILE * fp, grafo *robots, lista *celulas, listarobots *posicoes)
{
    int naofaznada,tamanho=0, i, x, y, xmax, xmin, ymax, ymin, v=1,dest,poslst, origem,id=0;
    char nome[16], aux;
    xmax=xmin=ymax=ymin=0;
    celulas=lista_nova();
    lista_insere(celulas, 0,0,0);
    fp = fopen("input.txt", "r");
    robots = grafo_novo(tamanho,NAODIRECIONADO);
    posicoes=listarobots_nova();
    fscanf( fp, " %c", &aux);
    while (aux!=EOF)
    {
        for (i=0;aux!= ',';i++)
        {
            nome[i]=aux;
            nome[i+1]='\0';
            fscanf(fp, " %c", &aux);
        }
        fscanf(fp, " %c", &aux);
        poslst=listarobot_pesquisa(posicoes, nome, &x, &y, &naofaznada);
        if(poslst==-1)
        {
            if(aux=='D')
            {
                x=0;
                y=-1;

            }
            if(aux=='U')
            {
                x=0;
                y=1;
            }
            if(aux=='L')
            {
                x=-1;
                y=0;
            }
            if(aux=='R')
            {
                x=1;
                y=0;
            }
            listarobots_insere(posicoes, nome, x, y, id);
            id++;
            origem=0;
            if(x>xmax) xmax=x;
            if(x<xmin) xmin=x;
            if(y>ymax) ymax=y;
            if(y<ymin) ymin=y;
            if(lista_pesquisa(celulas, x, y)==-1)
            {
                lista_insere(celulas, x, y, v);
                dest=v;
                v++;


                grafo_adiciona(robots, 0, dest);
                if(lista_pesquisa(celulas, (x+1),y)!=-1) grafo_adiciona(robots, dest, lista_pesquisa(celulas, (x+1), y));
                if(lista_pesquisa(celulas, (x-1),y)!=-1) grafo_adiciona(robots, dest, lista_pesquisa(celulas, (x-1), y));
                if(lista_pesquisa(celulas, x,(y+1))!=-1) grafo_adiciona(robots, dest, lista_pesquisa(celulas, x, (y+1)));
                if(lista_pesquisa(celulas, x,(y-1))!=-1) grafo_adiciona(robots, dest, lista_pesquisa(celulas, x, (y-1)));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            origem=lista_pesquisa(celulas,x, y);
            if(aux=='D')
            {
                y=y-1;

            }
            if(aux=='U')
            {
                y=y+1;
            }
            if(aux=='L')
            {
                x=x-1;
            }
            if(aux=='R')
            {
                x=x+1;
            }
            listarobot_atribui(posicoes, poslst, x, y);


        }
        if(x>xmax) xmax=x;
        if(x<xmin) xmin=x;
        if(y>ymax) ymax=y;
        if(y<ymin) ymin=y;
        if(lista_pesquisa(celulas, x, y)==-1)
        {
            lista_insere(celulas, x, y, v);
            dest=v;
            v++;


            grafo_adiciona(robots, origem, dest);
            if(lista_pesquisa(celulas, (x+1),y)!=-1) grafo_adiciona(robots, dest, lista_pesquisa(celulas, (x+1), y));
            if(lista_pesquisa(celulas, (x-1),y)!=-1) grafo_adiciona(robots, dest, lista_pesquisa(celulas, (x-1), y));
            if(lista_pesquisa(celulas, x,(y+1))!=-1) grafo_adiciona(robots, dest, lista_pesquisa(celulas, x, (y+1)));
            if(lista_pesquisa(celulas, x,(y-1))!=-1) grafo_adiciona(robots, dest, lista_pesquisa(celulas, x, (y-1)));
        }
        if(fscanf(fp, " %c", &aux)==EOF) break;
        if(aux=='?')
        {
            *wx=x;
            *wy=y;
            if(fscanf(fp, " %c", &aux)==EOF) break;
        }
        if(aux=='!')
        {
            *fimx=x;
            *fimy=y;
            if(fscanf(fp, " %c", &aux)==EOF) break;
        }

    }
    *tamx= xmax-xmin+1;
    *tamy= ymax-ymin +1;
    *xminfinal=xmin;
    *yminfinal=ymin;
    return ;
}

void mapeamento(FILE * out, int x, int y, int ymin, int xmin, int wx, int wy, int fimx, int fimy, lista* celulas )
{
    int xatual, yatual;
    for(yatual=ymin+ y-1; yatual!=ymin-1;yatual--)
    {
        for(xatual=xmin; xatual!=xmin+x; xatual++)
        {
            if((xatual==0) && (yatual==0)) fprintf(out," e ");
            else if((xatual==wx)&&(yatual==wy)) fprintf(out, " w ");
            else if((xatual==fimx)&&(yatual==fimy)) fprintf(out, " s ");
            else if(lista_pesquisa(celulas, x, y)==-1) fprintf(out, " * ");
            else if(lista_pesquisa(celulas, x, y)!=-1)fprintf(out, " . ");
            if(xatual==fimx) fprintf(out, "\n");
        }

    }
    return;
}

void caminhos(int wx, int wy, int fimx, int fimy, lista* celulas, FILE *fp, FILE *out, grafo *robots, listarobots* posicoes)
{
    int restantes,nfnx,nfny,i,id,is,antx,anty,novox,novoy,tamanhocaminho1,tamanhocaminho2, *caminho1, *caminho2, *posrobots;
    char *caminho,nome[16], aux;
    caminho1=grafo_bfs(robots, 0, lista_pesquisa(celulas, wx, wy), &tamanhocaminho1);
    caminho2=grafo_bfs(robots, lista_pesquisa(celulas, wx, wy), lista_pesquisa(celulas, fimx, fimy), &tamanhocaminho2);
    caminho= malloc((tamanhocaminho1+tamanhocaminho2)*sizeof(char));
    antx=0;
    anty=0;
    is=0;
    for(i=1; i<tamanhocaminho1; i++, is++)
    {
        lista_xy(celulas, caminho1[i], &novox, &novoy);
        if((novox-antx)==1) caminho[is]= 'R';
        else if((novox-antx)==-1) caminho[is]= 'L';
        else if((novoy-anty)==-1) caminho[is]= 'D';
        else if((novoy-anty)==1) caminho[is]= 'U';
        antx=novox;
        anty=novoy;
    }
    for(i=1; i<tamanhocaminho2; i++, is++)
    {
        lista_xy(celulas, caminho1[i], &novox, &novoy);
        if((novox-antx)==1) caminho[is]= 'R';
        else if((novox-antx)==-1) caminho[is]= 'L';
        else if((novoy-anty)==-1) caminho[is]= 'D';
        else if((novoy-anty)==1) caminho[is]= 'U';
        antx=novox;
        anty=novoy;
    }
    caminho[is]='\0';
    fprintf(out, "\n\n%s\n", caminho);
    free(caminho1);
    free(caminho2);
    fclose(fp);
    fp=fopen("input.txt", "r");
    restantes=posicoes->tamanho;
    posrobots=calloc (posicoes->tamanho, sizeof(int));
    fscanf(fp, " %c", &aux);
    while (aux!=EOF)
    {
        for (i=0;aux!= ',';i++)
        {
            nome[i]=aux;
            nome[i+1]='\0';
            fscanf(fp, " %c", &aux);
        }
        fscanf(fp, " %c", &aux);
        listarobot_pesquisa(posicoes, nome, &nfnx, &nfny, &id);
        if(posrobots[id]==-1) nfnx=1;
        else if(caminho[posrobots[id]]==aux) posrobots[id]++;
        else
        {
            posrobots[id]=-1;
            restantes--;
        }
        if(posrobots[id]==is) fprintf(out, "%s\n", nome);
        fscanf(fp, " %c", &aux);
        if(aux=='?')
        {
            fscanf(fp, " %c", &aux);
        }
        if(aux=='!')
        {
            fscanf(fp, " %c", &aux);
        }
    }
    if(restantes==0) fprintf(out, "0\n");

}

void output()
{

}

int main()
{
    FILE *fp, *out;
    grafo *robots;
    lista *celulas;
    listarobots *posicoes;
    celulas=(lista * )malloc(sizeof(lista));
    robots=(grafo * )malloc(sizeof(grafo));
    posicoes=(listarobots * )malloc(sizeof(listarobots));
    fp=(FILE * )malloc(sizeof(FILE));
    out=(FILE * )malloc(sizeof(FILE));
    int x,y,xmin, ymin,wx,wy,fimx,fimy;
    out=fopen("output.txt", "w");
    leitura(&x, &y, &xmin, &ymin,&wx, &wy, &fimx, &fimy, fp, robots, celulas, posicoes);
    fprintf(out,"largura:%d, altura:%d\n", x, y );
    mapeamento(out, x, y, ymin, xmin, wx, wy, fimx, fimy, celulas);
    //caminhos(wx, wy,fimx, fimy,celulas, fp, out, robots, posicoes);
    return 0;
}
```

the extra includes dont make a difference, I've checked and the errors are on this block of code, but just in case, I'll post here the code for the include "grafo.h"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "grafo.h"

/* cria no da lista de adjacencias */
lista_no* cria_no(int v)
{
    lista_no* novo = (lista_no*)malloc(sizeof(lista_no));
    if(!novo)
        return NULL;

    novo->vertice = v;
    novo->proximo = NULL;

    return novo;
}

/* cria grafo com n vertices */
grafo* grafo_novo(int n, tipo_grafo tipo)
{
    grafo* g = (grafo*)malloc(sizeof(grafo));
    lista_no novo;
    if(g == NULL)
        return NULL;

    g->tamanho = 1;
    g->tipo = tipo;

    /* cria array de listas de adjacencias */
    g->adjacencias = (lista_adj*)calloc(n, sizeof(lista_adj));
    if(g->adjacencias == NULL)
    {
        free(g);
        return NULL;
    }
    g->adjacencias[0].inicio=NULL;


    return g;
}

/* apaga grafo e liberta memoria */
void grafo_apaga(grafo* g)
{
    if(g == NULL)
        return;

    if(g->adjacencias != NULL)
    {
        int v;
        for (v = 0; v < g->tamanho; v++)
        {
            while (g->adjacencias[v].inicio)
            {
                lista_no* aux = g->adjacencias[v].inicio;
                g->adjacencias[v].inicio = g->adjacencias[v].inicio->proximo;
                free(aux);
            }
        }
        free(g->adjacencias);
    }
    free(g);
}

/* adiciona uma aresta ao grafo*/
void grafo_adiciona(grafo *g, int origem, int dest)
{
    lista_no* novo,*aux,*ant;

    if (g == NULL || grafo_existe(g, origem, dest))
        return;

    /* adiciona uma aresta de origem para dest na lista de adjacencias */
    novo = cria_no(dest);
    novo->proximo = NULL;
    g->adjacencias = (lista_adj*)realloc(g->adjacencias, (g->tamanho+1)*sizeof(lista_adj));
    g->adjacencias[dest].inicio=NULL;
    g->tamanho++;
    ant= aux =g->adjacencias[origem].inicio;
    if(ant==NULL) g->adjacencias[origem].inicio=novo;
    else
    {
        aux=ant->proximo;

        while(aux!=NULL)
        {
            ant=aux;
            aux=ant->proximo;
        }
        ant->proximo=novo;
    }
    g->adjacencias[origem].tamanho++;

    if(g->tipo == NAODIRECIONADO)
    {
        /* adiciona tambem aresta de dest para origem */
        novo = cria_no(origem);
        novo->proximo = NULL;
        ant= aux =g->adjacencias[dest].inicio;
        if(ant==NULL) g->adjacencias[dest].inicio=novo;
        else
        {
            aux=ant->proximo;
            while(aux!=NULL)
            {
                ant=aux;
                aux=ant->proximo;
            }
            ant->proximo=novo;
        }
        g->adjacencias[dest].tamanho++;
    }
}

/* remove uma aresta do grafo*/
void grafo_remove(grafo *g, int origem, int dest)
{
    lista_no *aux, *prev;

    if (g == NULL || g->adjacencias[origem].inicio == NULL)
        return;

    aux = g->adjacencias[origem].inicio;
    /* caso especial: primeiro no' da lista */
    if(aux->vertice == dest)
    {
        g->adjacencias[origem].inicio = aux->proximo;
        free(aux);
    }
    else
    {
        prev = aux;
        aux = aux->proximo;
        while(aux != NULL)
        {
            if(aux->vertice == dest)
            {
                prev->proximo = aux->proximo;
                free(aux);
                break;
            }
            prev = aux;
            aux = aux->proximo;
        }
    }

    if(g->tipo == NAODIRECIONADO)
    {
        /* remove tambem aresta de dest para origem */
        /* caso especial: primeiro no' da lista */
        aux = g->adjacencias[dest].inicio;
        if(aux->vertice == origem)
        {
            g->adjacencias[dest].inicio = aux->proximo;
            free(aux);
        }
        else
        {
            prev = aux;
            aux = aux->proximo;
            while(aux != NULL)
            {
                if(aux->vertice == origem)
                {
                    prev->proximo = aux->proximo;
                    free(aux);
                    break;
                }
                prev = aux;
                aux = aux->proximo;
            }
        }
    }

}

/* verifica se existe uma aresta entre os vertices origem e dest */
int grafo_existe(grafo *g, int origem, int dest)
{
    if (g == NULL)
        return 0;

    lista_no* aux = g->adjacencias[origem].inicio;
    while (aux)
    {
        if(aux->vertice == dest)
            return 1;
        aux = aux->proximo;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* imprime as listas de adjacencias do grafo */
void grafo_imprime(grafo* g)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < g->tamanho; i++)
    {
        lista_no* aux = g->adjacencias[i].inicio;
        printf("%d: ", i);
        if(aux)
        {
            printf("%d", aux->vertice);
            aux = aux->proximo;

            while (aux)
            {
                printf("->%d", aux->vertice);
                aux = aux->proximo;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int dfs_helper(grafo *g, int inicio, int fim, int profundidade, int *visitados)
{
    int i, d;

    if(visitados[inicio])
        return 0;

    visitados[inicio] = profundidade;

    if(inicio == fim)
        return profundidade;

    for(i=0; i < g->tamanho; i++)
    {
        if(grafo_existe(g, inicio, i))
        {
            d = dfs_helper(g, i, fim, profundidade + 1, visitados);
            if(d)
                return d;
        }
    }
    visitados[inicio] = 0;
    return 0;
}

/* retorna caminho entre origem e dest usando depth-first search (DFS)
   n guarda o tamanho do caminho
   nao garante caminho mais curto */
int* grafo_dfs(grafo *g, int inicio, int fim, int *n)
{
    int *visitados, *caminho;
    int profundidade, i, ret_i;

    if(g==NULL)
        return 0;

    visitados = calloc(g->tamanho, sizeof(int));
    profundidade = dfs_helper(g, inicio, fim, 1, visitados);

    if(profundidade == 0)
    {
        free(visitados);
        *n=0;
        return NULL;
    }

    /* reconstrucao do caminho */
    caminho = calloc(profundidade, sizeof(int));
    for (ret_i = 0; ret_i < profundidade; ret_i++)
        for (i = 0; i< g->tamanho; i++)
            if(visitados[i] == ret_i + 1)
            {
                caminho[ret_i] = i;
                break;
            }
    *n = profundidade;
    free(visitados);
    return caminho;
}


/* retorna caminho entre origem e dest usando breadth-first search (BFS)
   n guarda o tamanho do caminho
   garante caminho mais curto */
int* grafo_bfs(grafo *g, int inicio, int fim, int *n)
{
    int *caminho, *visitados, *fila;
    int profundidade, i, j, fila_inicio = 0, fila_fim=0;

    if(g==NULL)
        return 0;

    visitados = calloc(g->tamanho, sizeof(int));
    fila = calloc(g->tamanho, sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < g->tamanho; i++)
        visitados[i] = -1;

    visitados[inicio] = inicio;
    fila[fila_fim++] = inicio;

    while(fila_inicio != fila_fim)
    {
        i = fila[fila_inicio];
        fila_inicio = (fila_inicio + 1) % g->tamanho;
        for(j = 0; j < g->tamanho; j++)
            if(grafo_existe(g, i, j) && visitados[j] == -1)
            {
                visitados[j] = i;
                fila[fila_fim] = j;
                fila_fim = (fila_fim + 1) % g->tamanho;
            }
    }

    /* reconstrucao do caminho */
    profundidade = 0;
    if(visitados[fim] >= 0)
    {
        int tmp = fim;
        profundidade = 1;
        while(visitados[tmp] != tmp)
        {
            profundidade++;
            tmp = visitados[tmp];
        }

        caminho = malloc(profundidade  * sizeof(int));
        tmp = fim;
        i = 0;
        while(i++ < profundidade)
        {
            caminho[profundidade - i] = tmp;
            tmp = visitados[tmp];
        }
    }

    free(fila);
    free(visitados);

    *n=profundidade;
    return caminho;
}
```

And the warnings are:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]  trabalho.c  /trabalho/src   line 110    C/C++ Problem
assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]  trabalho.c  /trabalho/src   line 135    C/C++ Problem
assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]  trabalho.c  /trabalho/src   line 95 C/C++ Problem
```

I appreciate any and all the help you can offer. I am still pretty new at programming and this warnings are completely messing with my mind.

Comment: Please provide a *much* smaller code snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I'm casting a vote as "too broad" - I don't know how much this specific example, without any simplication, will be useful to future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're assigning `proximo` (which are pointers to `_elemento`) to variables that are pointers to `robot_lista`.

Comment: thank you, this helped a lot =)
now I just need to revise my code to check how I'm going to change it XP
but you were extremely helpful, thank you so much

Comment: that did solve the warnings, thank you, but no luck making it run as it should have. but still, your answer helped a lot, thank you.